# No module named thrift in Python script

Tags: python, homebrew, thrift

I've installed Thrift on my Mac using Homebrew: brew install thrift --with-python

That did some work and finished w/o errors reported.  I have thrift on my path.

I write a simple python client from a tutorial: (there is some python thrift code in gen-py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
sys.path.append("./gen-py")

from thrift import Thrift
from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol

# rest of program...
```

When run I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hey.py", line 8, in <module>
    from thrift import Thrift
ImportError: No module named thrift
```

Did I installed python correctly using Homebrew?  Is there a way I can verify the python/thrift integration is installed properly?

Comment: I'm not a pytthon guy, but have you included the Thrift library code as well? There are two parts, the generated code in `gen-py` and the library code.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out the (current at time of this writing) Homebrew recipe for Thrift installation doesn't fully install everything for python, specifically the libraries.  (It does successfully install the thrift command-line tools.)

I fixed this by downloading the python distribution and building it on my Mac--but not installing since I'd already done a brew install.  I just wanted the python libs.

I followed advice here: http://thrift-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage-example.html
I ran "sudo python setup.py install" as described and this correctly (apparently) installed the needed libs and things worked after that.

Comment: Could you just raise the issue on the Thrift mailing list? Maybe already solved with 0.9.2 but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: Still ran into the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this problem on my macOS Mojave 10.14.1. And it seems the reason is that `--with-python` will install `python@2` and the `thrift` module inside it. However, you are using the system `python`, which is different from the `python@2`. You may verify this by `brew list | grep python` and you should see the following result.

```
python
python@2
```

After removing `python@2` (`brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python@2`) and installing the python module from the source should work.

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/thrift.git
cd thrift/lib/py
sudo python setup.py install
```

For more details about the cause, you may refer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981663/python2-7-broken-by-weakref-import-error-please-help).

Answer (score 2):

Removing  `python@2` `(brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python@2)` did not work for me. In fact, I had to reinstall `brew install python@2`

`pip install thrift` worked for me.

My system was OSX Mojave and python 2.7.
`brew list | grep python` had following result:

`python
python@2`

Answer (score 2):

I am not using Mac / Homebrew, but here is how I solved this issue:

I am using Linux, and my Thrift server ran fine in PyCharm, but I was getting the **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thrift'** error when running from the command line.

It turned out that although I had Thrift installed on my system, I had not installed it using Pip.  Once I ran:

**pip install thrift**

... Everything worked fine.